# Expect Assertions not working in Nightwatch

Tags: chai, nightwatch.js

I am currently using Nightwatch to test a site running on an MVC controller. All other Nightwatch commands and assertions are working, but when I try to use Expect assertions I get an error:

> .expect.element(...).to.be.present is not a function

The element is definitely on the dom and I have the 
I have tried requiring `chai-nightwatch` in my globals file generally and by specifically assigning it to `expect`, but they continue to error out when I run the test.

Answer (score 0):

client.expect.element().to.be.present WORKS